# getting AdMob Mediation ID

Tags: ios, admob, ads

**Straight to the point:**
I understand what is mediationID and why it's for, but I can't get `mediationID` on [admob](https://apps.admob.com/) tool.

[Mediation ad network guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation) looks like this:

But reality is that I can't find `Mediation ID`.

[image]

**What I did:**

- Created AdMob account
- Created test app
- Added custom ad network

[image]
I have ability to set adaptor "Class Name", label, parameters, but the problem remains I can't find anywhere mediationID to use instead of adUnitID.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ID you are seeing that looks like 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXX/NNNNN" **IS** your mediation id.

Comment: yep.. got it. Since they have new dashboard mediation works automatically and I can use my adUnitID

Comment: Hey guys, can you confirm in the new interface UNIT ID = MEDIATION ID? I am having difficulties to find more info confirming that (well, I have only found... this page!) and at the same time, I cannot find any way to get mediation id with the new interface. Bottom line, you are most probably right, but it would nice to have 1 or 2 other sources confirming this.

Comment: Yes, in the new Admob interface the adUnitId is your mediationId.

Comment: Thanks for confirming William. After other searches I also came to the same conclusion so now I'm sure :)

Comment: Hey, i just read " If you were using mediation, we referred to the identifier as “mediation ID”, which represented a string of 16 character hexadecimal characters such as e123456789012345.", so what is the difference here?

Comment: I have used ca-app-pub-XXXXXXX/NNNNN in my code, but in another app my client has provided me the admob with 15 character.

Comment: That is the adUnitId for the old Admob site. Read that blogpost again. Note the para you reference starts with "Previously, ". And the next para "In the new AdMob, this identifier is referred to as “ad unit ID” and has a format of ca-app-<publisherId>/<slotname>. The term publisherId now represents a unique account identifier with the format pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (16 digits) and slotname identifies a unique ad space and has the format nnnnnnnnnn (10 digits)."

Comment: Pretty confusing, I can't seem to find mediation ID anywhere on AdMob's web console. Does anyone know where to find it ? Thanks!

Comment: On the Monetize page, select your app and underneath each AdUnit you will see the ids.